# multiple services with one jobrunr storage

Tags: spring-boot, jobrunr

I'd like to use jobrunr in multiple services (spring-boot apps) running with one DB, where jobrunr storage is. Is it possible to provide a custom storage provider, so each apps loads only jobs i.e. prefixed with the app name?

Or maybe there is other way around to solve my problem which is:
When another app starts and connects to the same storage (where there are already defined recurring jobs) it tries to run these recurring job and fails:
Job(id=f6f51cb7-a4b3-4206-98a7-7b8a6b7d4132, jobName='JOB-NAME') processing failed: Job method not found.

thanks,
Chris

Comment: What is the reason you only want to use one DB?

Comment: These are quite small services operating mostly on Elasticsearch data but also sharing same DB schema. They are small for better deployment/maintenance. 
I've reviewed your code and see the easiest way for me would be to overwrite JobTable class adding conditions to methods returning jobs i.e. selectJobsByState etc.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://www.jobrunr.io/en/documentation/configuration/spring/

You can set org.jobrunr.database.table-prefix per service in your application.properties, so that your services will use shared storage but they will operate on separate database tables.